# How To Test with Http locally with stripe v2 api?

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

Up until now, I've not been having problem testing my stripe api v2 on my localhost.  My app makes jquery ajax calls to a localhost http service and of course stripe uses https.  I just started getting the error below.

How can I test my app locally where I don't have an https cert installed?

> "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:17138" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://js.stripe.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol
>   of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https"."

My call that triggers the error is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/rpc/account/UpdateAttendeeRegJqueryHackathon',
    data: {...
```

Comment: 99% of the time, it's just a warning, the token is still created, the code still works. I'd just ignore it once you confirm that the token is sent back by Stripe.js

Answer (score 2):

This is really odd, but it turned out that I had forgot a () on a val and without that, I get this error, with it I do not get the error.

That is, I had this:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/rpc/account/UpdateAttendeeRegJqueryHackathon',
                data: {
                    HackathonConfirmed:  $('#HackathonConfirmed').val,
                    UserFirstName: $('#UserFirstName').val(),
```

instead of

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/rpc/account/UpdateAttendeeRegJqueryHackathon',
                data: {
                    HackathonConfirmed:  $('#HackathonConfirmed').val(),
                    UserFirstName: $('#UserFirstName').val(),
```

and that made the problem go away.  I'm baffled but thought I would post anyhow in the hopes it helps someone else or someone explains why val without a () causes the http/https mismatch